# If $T\in L(H_1, H_2)$ has a finite rank then so does $T^*$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question was asked in my assignment of Functional Analysis and I am not sure how should I attempt this. I have been following functional analysis by Walter Rudin.

So, I am asking for help here.

> Let $H_1 $ and $H_2$ be hilbert spaces. Show that if $T\in L(H_1,H_2) $ has a finite rank , then show that $T^*$ also has a finite rank.

I don't have any clue on how this particular proposition can be proved.

I am sorry but what can I show in attempt?

If $T\in L(H_1,H_2) $ then there exists $T^* \in L(H_1,H_2)$ . such that $<Tx,y> = <x,T^*y>$.

Comment: Hints: the restriction of $T$ to the orthogonal complement of $\ker T$ is an isomorphism onto the range of $T$, so these have the same rank. Now use the definition of the adjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not too straightforward way to do it, but it shines light over what these operators look like. One can get a very explicit form for these operators.

If $T$ is finite-rank, let $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ be an orthonormal basis of its range. Then for any $x$ we have
$$
Tx=\sum_{j=1}^m c_j\,g_j
$$
for some coefficients $c_j$. The fact that $g_1,\ldots,g_m$ are an orthonormal basis implies that $c_j=\langle Tx,g_j\rangle$, which are bounded linear functionals. If we put $h_j=T^*g_j$, we get
$$
Tx=\sum_{j=1}^m \langle x,h_j\rangle g_j. 
$$
Now
\begin{align}
\langle T^*y,x\rangle
&=\langle y,Tx\rangle
=\sum_{j=1}^m\overline{\langle x,h_j\rangle}\,\langle y,g_j\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\sum_{j=1}^m {\langle h_j,x\rangle}\,\langle y,g_j\rangle\\[0.3cm]
&=\Big\langle\sum_{j=1}^m\langle y,g_j\rangle\,h_j,x\Big\rangle.
\end{align}
As this can be done for any $x$,
$$
T^*=\sum_{j=1}^m\langle\cdot,g_j\rangle\,h_j
$$
is finite-rank.